# How do you read the bundle identifier of an application from within a sandboxed application?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-foundation, appkit

I'm attempting to add functionality to an application that is similar in function to the "Open With..." menu in the Finder. In the application I'm working on, a user can select a file and chose to open it with a specific application, rather than with the default one.

The problem I'm experiencing is that there appears to be a mis-match in the APIs I think I should be using in order for this to work properly. Specifically, the recommended `NSWorkspace` API for opening files with a specific application takes a bundle identifier to specifying the application:

```
[NSWorkspace                openURLs: 
             withAppBundleIdentifier:
                             options:
      additionalEventParamDescriptor:
                   launchIdentifiers:]
```

However, the Launch Services API for getting a list of applications that can open a given file returns an array of URLs, each pointing to a compatible application:

`CFArrayRef LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL(CFURLRef inURL, LSRolesMask inRoleMask);`

Currently, I'm iterating over the array that launch services returns and extracting the bundle identifier by creating a new NSBundle each time:

```
for (NSURL *applicationURL in applicationURLs) {
  NSBundle *applicationBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:applicationURL];
  NSString *bundleIdentifier = applicationBundle.bundleIdentifier;

  // Do something with bundle identifier...
}
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that if the `applicationURL` points to an application that is not under `/Applications` (or any other directory my sandboxed application has read access to), then I cannot create an `NSBundle` to read the  bundle identifier. Instead, Gate Keeper will output a sandbox violation to Console.app and `NSBundle bundleWithURL` will return nil.

Is there a way I've overlooked to get the bundle identifier from a URL that I've overlooked? Or is there a different way to read the bundle identifier from an arbitrary file without causing a sandbox violation? Or maybe there's a different way to get a list of all applications that can open a specific URL?

(Note that the Launch Services method to open multiple URLs, `LSOpenURLsWithRole` has been deprecated. The header file simply says "Use NSWorkspace".)

Comment: I can't believe there's no good answer after 4 years of this...